# Tabbing doesnt work for datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I m using jquery datatables in many pages and its working good in every page and in a single page its not working properly, i mean when i use tab to go through datatable, it works fine for the first time and when i try to do the same for second time, if i try to focus on any thing in few seconds in data table, the focus disappears and the foucs starts from the starting of the page.

Here goes the code

```
function tableCall(){
    var clientId = $('#clientId').val();
    var versionCount = $('#versionCount').val();
    var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
    var toDate = $('#toDate').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: auditTrail.props.reporttableURL,
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        clientId:clientId,
        versionCount:versionCount,
        fromDate:fromDate,
        toDate:toDate
      },
      success: function (data) {
            searchJSON = data.data;
            var len=searchJSON.length;
            if (len > 0){                   
                $('.no-data, #warning-sign').hide();
                createTable();
            }else{
                $('.no-data').hide();
                $('#warning-sign').show();
            }
      }
    });
}

function createTable() {
     wwhs.setADAAttrDynamic($('#auditTable'));
      if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#auditTable')) {
       // table.destroy();
        $("#auditTable tbody").empty();
    }
    table = $('#auditTable').dataTable({
        "searching":false,
        "destroy":true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "destroy":true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "drawCallback": attachEvents,
         "stateLoadParams": function (settings, data) {
                return false;
            },
        data: searchJSON,


        columns: [{
            data: "reportName"
        }, {
            data: "reportStatus"
        }, {
            data: "timeStamp"
        }, {
            data: "requestedBy"
      }],

        "columnDefs": [{
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                if(row.reportStatus.toUpperCase() == 'PROCESSED')
                    return '<a class="blue-text" " data-name="'+ row.reportName +'">' + row.reportName + '</a>';
                else
                    return row.reportName;
            },
            "width": "50%",
            "targets": 0
        }, {
            "width": "15%",
            "targets": 1
        }, {
            "width": "20%",
            "targets": 2
        }, {
            "width": "15%",
            "targets": 3
        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: instead of `$("#auditTable tbody").empty();` you should destroy the table using the API given by `DataTables`

Comment: thnks bro, it helped

Comment: if the answer helped you, consider supporting it by accepting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because the datatable instance is not destroyed.

Since datatables saves all the nodes into an object and renders it when ever it wants, emptying the tbody doesnt do anything. it just removes the elements in the page which can be re-drawn/re-rendered by `datatable` from its stored object.

You can check if the object is already initialized and the destroy it before re-initializing.

```
if(typeof table != "undefined")
    table.destroy();
```

So the final code will look something like

```
function tableCall(){
    var clientId = $('#clientId').val();
    var versionCount = $('#versionCount').val();
    var fromDate = $('#fromDate').val();
    var toDate = $('#toDate').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: auditTrail.props.reporttableURL,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            clientId:clientId,
            versionCount:versionCount,
            fromDate:fromDate,
            toDate:toDate
        },
        success: function (data) {
            searchJSON = data.data;
            var len=searchJSON.length;
            if (len > 0){                   
                $('.no-data, #warning-sign').hide();
                createTable();
            } else {
                $('.no-data').hide();
                $('#warning-sign').show();
            }
        }
    });
}

function createTable() {
    wwhs.setADAAttrDynamic($('#auditTable'));
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#auditTable')) {
        if(typeof table != "undefined")
            table.destroy();
    }
    table = $('#auditTable').dataTable({
        "searching":false,
        "destroy":true,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "ordering": true,
        "destroy":true,
        "stateSave": true,
        "drawCallback": attachEvents,
        "stateLoadParams": function (settings, data) {
            return false;
        },
        data: searchJSON,
        columns: [{
            data: "reportName"
        }, {
            data: "reportStatus"
        }, {
            data: "timeStamp"
        }, {
            data: "requestedBy"
        }],

        "columnDefs": [{
            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                if(row.reportStatus.toUpperCase() == 'PROCESSED')
                    return '<a class="blue-text" " data-name="'+ row.reportName +'">' + row.reportName + '</a>';
                else
                    return row.reportName;
            },
            "width": "50%",
            "targets": 0
        }, {
            "width": "15%",
            "targets": 1
        }, {
            "width": "20%",
            "targets": 2
        }, {
            "width": "15%",
            "targets": 3
        }]
    });
}
```